# Github user-machine

Tags: github

I want to create so-called user machine for automation needs (CI/CD and data platform), so something not linked with "human-based" activities.

If you read the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#machine-users), it's not so clear about what kind of user can be a user machine. Can we explictly declare such an account as a "machine" ?

And also, does this count as a seat on our paid bill ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a user. No flags anywhere. And yes they consume a license.

If your tools support it, installing them as a GitHub App is a better way to go.

If you are taking the machine user approach, consider using the new scoped access tokens for extra security.